# Wanted to know is anyone has come across this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $n$th term of sequence be $b(n)$.

$b(0)= 0$

For $n\ge 1$

when $n$ is odd: $b(n)=b(n-1)+n$

when $n$ is even: $b(n)=b(n-1)=2n$

I found an interesting pattern which corresponded to this series so wanted to know if anyone has ever seen this?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence (assuming you meant to write $b(n)=b(n-1)+2n$) seems to be https://oeis.org/A001082. In general, if you want to identify an integer sequence, you should always first search oeis.

Comment: Hey thanks so much did not know about this website will do so now onwards.